# How to simulate a torque wrench?

Tags: torque

Two-part question here, concerning the real-world application of torque.

I have a bolt on my vehicle that I have to tighten to about 200 ft-lbs.  But my torque wrench is only calibrated for up to 150 ft-lbs.

If I sheathe the end of my regular ratchet with a 4-foot "cheater pipe", and then hang a 50 lb weight at the end of that 4-foot moment until the bolt stops turning, I believe the torque will then be greater than 200 ft-lbs  (because the 4-foot galvanized steel pipe itself has significant weight.)

My two-part question is:

1. Is my intuition for accurately simulating a torque wrench correct?
2. How might I account for the weight of the (straight, uniform) pipe in a manner that is physically correct?  (This seems like possibly an integration problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your intuition is correct.  Absent the weight of the pipe and your ratchet, you will produce 200 ft-lbs this way.  I suspect the weight of the pipe is a small error compared to others in the system, but if we model the pipe as a uniform beam we can check.  Let the mass of the pipe be $m$ lbs.  The mass of a small length $dx$ is then $\frac m4 \ dx$ lbs.  The torque applied is then $\int_0^4 \frac m4gx\ dx=mg\frac{x^2}8|_0^4=2mg$  As your english scale reads $mg$, this is twice the reading on your scale.  If the pipe weighs $2$ lbs, it is only a $2\%$ error.  You can reduce your $50$ lb weight to $50-\frac m2$ lb to compensate, if you wish.

Comment: Half the weight of the pipe... nice.   Thank you for the clear and detailed answer.

Comment: Note that both the original premise of the questionand this answer only apply if the bar is horizontal.

Comment: @PeterGreen: or if the weight of the bar is negligible compared to the torque required to turn the bolt.  It appears that OP understands this.